# Expanding and Collapsing Div via Jquery & CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to make the div's expand/collapse on the jquery "click function" I have created. The difference between my question and other questions is the fact that I need to keep the maximum size at "120px" for the div's while they are in their "collapsed" state, and then need the height to be "100%" when it is in the "expanded" state.

Each parent div (i.e. div id = "1") is dynamically created from the SQL database depending on the query which is all handled elsewhere. There will be multiple of these div's on one page (again, depending on the query of the user).

Here is a jsfiddle URL to my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/m22Gu/17/

Comment: What is your question?  You are correctly adding/removing a class upon click and using the CSS on that class to control the state.  That is the recommended way to do something like this.  Are you asking for help with the specific CSS for both states?

Comment: Hmm.. the problem is it's not doing what I expected it to do. Try clicking on the div and see what happens. It just bounces up and down for me. Thanks.

Comment: I want to know how to make the div expand so that the full text can be seen. When the user is finished viewing that, they should be able to click it and it should collapse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this close to what you're after?

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/m22Gu/18/)

You can't use the slideToggle if you want content to remain visible. Instead simply animate the height of the divs.

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I was looking for. I don't know how to show you how happy I am, after spending three days trying to do this (I'm still learning). Just one quick one, how do I make them all expand along with the description div? It looks very weird at the moment.

Comment: Glad to help.. To expand them all, you need to move the click event to the parent div and then animate the children. See here: (http://jsfiddle.net/m22Gu/24/) Note: you've got two elements with the same ID - which you shouldn't do. I added a class to the parent div so it could be called for the click event.

Comment: Ok, that works a lot better, again. There's just one more problem! :/. What happens is when I click it (on my actual page) the div on the right most moves way below the other two divs. Do you know what's causing this problem?

Comment: Probably due to the floats you have in place. You might want to use `display: inline-block;` rather than floats.

Comment: Hmm... That seems to make my div's inside the main div go all over the place, instead of side by side.

Comment: Realize that all I have is a small snippet of code, which was coded incorrectly to begin with due to the multiple identical IDs. Here's a better code structure ---> http://jsfiddle.net/m22Gu/27/ But, I do not know anything else which may be present on your page and what other elements need to be considered in your layout.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your help. I just need to try and make it work better from here.